# download, share, print not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, file

So i have one screen on which i display one report from web into flutter app webview. and on top od this webview i creted 3 buttons print share and download. but not nothing is working till now. for showing that report into webview and 3 buttons on top of that webview i used this code

```
           late InAppWebViewController _webViewController;
           Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                // height: 8.h,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.w),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 2,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 1),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 30.w,
                        // height: 4.0.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xFF787878), width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            printPDF();
                          },
                          color: Colors.white,
                          iconSize: 4.5.w,
                          icon: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Icon(Icons.local_printshop_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xFF787878)),
                              HoriVertiPadding(horizontalPadding: 1.0.h),
                              const Text('Print',
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF787878))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 30.w,
                        // height: 4.0.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xFF787878), width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await _shareAsPDF();
                          },
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                          iconSize: 4.5.w,
                          icon: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Icon(Icons.share_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xFF787878)),
                              HoriVertiPadding(horizontalPadding: 1.0.h),
                              const Text('Share',
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF787878))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 30.w,
                        // height: 4.0.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xFF787878), width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // downloadFile(context, widget.urlString);
                            _downloadAsPDF();
                          },
                          color: Colors.white,
                          iconSize: 4.5.w,
                          icon: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Icon(Icons.file_download_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xFF787878)),
                              HoriVertiPadding(horizontalPadding: 1.0.h),
                              const Text('Download',
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF787878))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrlRequest:
                      URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.urlString)),
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                    _webViewController = controller;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

this is my url

```
    String urlString =
     ("https://www.****************.php?medical_id=${widget.medicalId}&doctor_id=$doctorId&patient_id=${widget.patient.id}&clinic_id=$clinicId&user_id=$doctorId&auth_token=$authToken&language_code=$languageCode&print1=PRINT");
```

for share, print and download i used this code

```
   Future<Uint8List> _generatePDFBytes() async {
if (_webViewController == null) return Uint8List(0);
// Capture a screenshot
final pdf = await _webViewController.takeScreenshot();
// Check if the screenshot is generated successfully
if (pdf != null) {
  // Continue with PDF processing
  final Uint8List pdfBytes = Uint8List.fromList(pdf!);
  final String appDocDir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  const fileName = 'Report';
  final String pdfPath = '$appDocDir/$fileName.pdf';

  // Write the PDF file
  await File(pdfPath).writeAsBytes(pdfBytes);

  return pdfBytes;
} else {
  // Log an error if the screenshot is not generated
  print('Error generating screenshot');
  return Uint8List(0);
}
}
   Future<void> printPDF() async {
try {
  final Uint8List bytes = await _generatePDFBytes();
  await Printing.layoutPdf(
    onLayout: (_) async => bytes,
    name: 'Report.pdf',
    dynamicLayout: true,
  );
} catch (e) {
  print('Error during PDF printing: $e');
  // Handle the error appropriately.
}
 }

Future<void> _shareAsPDF() async {
final Uint8List bytes = await _generatePDFBytes();
final String appDocDir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
const fileName = 'Report';
final String pdfPath = '$appDocDir/$fileName.pdf';
await File(pdfPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
XFile xFile = XFile(pdfPath, name: fileName);
await Share.shareXFiles(
  [xFile],
);
}

Future<void> _downloadAsPDF() async {
try {
  final Uint8List bytes = await _generatePDFBytes();
  final String appDocDir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  const fileName = 'Report';
  final String pdfPath = '$appDocDir/$fileName.pdf';
  await File(pdfPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
  await OpenFile.open(pdfPath);
} catch (e) {
  print('Error opening PDF: $e');
}
}
```

but when i use print i am getting format error. please help